# LoginWithAmazon SDK for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, login-with-amazon

I'm making app with using Xamarin.Forms.

I want to integrate Amazon login so that I could use Amazon echo with my app.

There is a component here. 
https://components.xamarin.com/view/amazonlogin?version=2.1.0.0

but It's way out of date.
I don't think I could use this.
Any idea how can I resolve my issue?

There are some Amazon SDK for xamarin made by Amazon. 
https://developer.amazon.com/sdk-download
But it also does not seem usable. This have two folder named inapp and amazonad. and .xam file without documents.

Only option seems like a create webpage with using javascript provided from Amazon and use it via a webview.
https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/login-with-amazon/content/web_docs

Am I right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library on Xamarin Components website is a binding for the official Amazon SDKs.

You can create your own bindings for the native SDK to use them in Xamarin App, we have detailed instructions on our website here for both [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I think Xamarin has no plan currently to bind this plugin after saw your answer. I think I should do myself. I tried this solution before for binding another native library but failed. I should try again. Thanks.

Comment: Or using webview to get login token is still possible solution, isn't it?

Comment: Using Webview to get login token is still possible solution, if you think it's easier :)

Comment: Thanks again! :-)